# TypeError: JSON5.parse is not a function

Tags: json, parsing, require, json5

I have installed JSON5 by `npm install -d -g json5` and trying to parse the json string. But it is showing me `[[object Object]]JSON5.parse is not a function`. What the problem actually here is? and how we can resolve this? I am using the following code-

```
const JSON5 = require("json5")
var jsonV = JSON5.parse(fileStr)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Works for me. How are you running that program?

Comment: Running with typescript. I need this in vscode extension development.

Comment: Apparently it's a bug in vscode. See the rather long conversation in this bug report: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130367